# Unchecking all checkboxes having same class

Tags: jquery

I have a script which checks all the checkboxes that have same class.

However, I have put a condition of unchecking all of them which is not working.

Here's my code

```
function check_all() {
    if ($('#all_check').prop("checked")) {
        $('.chk').prop("checked", "true");
    } else {
        $('.chk').prop("checked", "false");
    }
}
```

The line `$('.chk').prop("checked", "false");` is having some problem, but what I can't find out.

Only this section of the code is not working.

Answer (score 8):

Just remove the quotes around `true` and `false`. They are data types and not strings.

```
function check_all() {
    if ($('#all_check').prop("checked")) {
        $('.chk').prop("checked", true);

    } else {
        $('.chk').prop("checked", false);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only problem I see in your code is the double quotes for `true` and `false`

```
function check_all() {
  if ($('#all_check').prop("checked")) {
    $('.chk').prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $('.chk').prop("checked", false);
  }
}
```

You may also simplify as follows,

```
function check_all() {
  $('.chk').prop("checked", $('#all_check').prop("checked"));
}
```

Because the `$('#all_check').prop("checked")` returns either `true` or `false`. So that will be set to the `checked` property of the checkboxes with class `.chk`

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
function check_all() {
     $('.chk').prop("checked", $('#all_check').is(":checked"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way:

```
function check_all() {
  $('.chk').prop( "checked", $('#all_check').is(":checked") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `""`.pass boolean

```
$('.chk').prop("checked", true);
$('.chk').prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`True` and `False` should be a boolean value. You assign string value in `prop` function.

```
 $('.chk').prop("checked", true);
 $('.chk').prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do with `.attr()` function in jQuery

```
function checkall() {
    $('.chk').attr('checked', $('#all_check').is(':checked'));
}
```